# Emacs: How to improve ido performance?

Tags: performance, emacs, ido

I found that if the ido completion list contains hundreds of items, it would be too slow to give completion suggestions.

I want to make use of ido's ability with high response speed. Any suggestions about how to fix the problem?

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/re5et/simp/issues/4#issuecomment-11924050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ido to complete Unicode character names, of which there are upwards of 30,000.  Ido was quite slow until I set `ido-enable-flex-matching` to nil for this single operation, and it immediately became essentially as fast as for any other matching operation.  Maybe this tactic can help you, too.

In a nutshell, I did this:

```
(let* ((ido-enable-flex-matching nil)
       (input (ido-completing-read prompt (ucs-names))))
  ; ...
)
```

Comment: Thank u! I will try this. But i also want "flex matching"